# Duda sobre ciclo For

Tags: r

Estaba intentando realizar el ejercicio del laboratorio y me surgen algunas dudas las que te preguntare ahora dado que no alcanzaré a estar mañana. Adjunto lo que llevo y el archivo que estoy utilizando de base
Hola, durante mi clase de R hicieron un ejercicio que permitiera determinar el IMC de cada persona y luego ir viendo en que categoria se adecúa. Les describo mas o menos lo que hice y dejo el codigo para ver en que estoy fallando.

Suponiendo que el script que quiero crear sirva para cualquier tabla que contenga la variable altura y peso utilizo el comando read.table y cargo mi tabla
Luego generé una columna extra que me determina el IMC

Luego quiero realizar un ciclo que me permita conocer la categoria (bajopeso, sobrepeso, obeso, normal) para lo cual hice un ciclo for con condicionales if, al ejecutar la funcion, el programa la reconoce y me la guarde en la caja de funciones, y una vez ejecutandola me arroja las categorias pero solo en la consola, ya que al querer guardarla como una variable, esta se genera pero como vacia (NULL)

Adjunto el codigo con la explicación paso a paso para ver si pueden ayudarme

```
setwd("C:/Users/tomas/Desktop/Magister/Cursos/Curso_R/Directorio")

#Definir columas del archivo txt
familia=read.table('familia.txt', header=TRUE, sep="")
peso=familia$peso
altura=familia$altura

#Determinar el IMC e incorporarlo al data.frame
imc=function(pes,alt){
  indice=pes/(alt^2)
  print(indice)
}

indice_masa_corporal=imc(peso,altura)
familia=cbind(familia,indice_masa_corporal)


#Determinar la categoria del IMC
imc_texto=function(p){
  bajopeso=("bajo peso")
  obeso=("obeso")
  normal=("normal")
  sobrepeso=("sobrepeso")
  for(n in p){
  if (n>=30){
    print(obeso)
  }else if (n<18.5){
    print(bajopeso)
  }else if (n<30 & n>25){
    print(sobrepeso)
  }else{
    print(normal)
  }
  }
}

condicion=imc_texto(indice_masa_corporal)
```

Una vez que ejecuto todo y creo una variable para guardar a que categoria (Bajopeso,sobrepeso,obeso,normal) se adecúa cada IMC, no se me genera un vector con el mismo numero de elementos que la columna que ingreso a la cual quiero que se le aplique mi función.

Si pudieran darme una mano con esto sería de gran ayuda

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Dos comentarios con respecto a `imc_texto`:

- El `print` es solo una salida por consola, lo que necesitas es retornar el valor calculado
- Como recibes un vector de entrada con múltiples valores, además, necesitas iterar por cada uno de ellos, calcular la categoría e ir "agregando" éstas a un nuevo vector que será la salida de tu función.

Básicamente algo así:

```
imc_texto = function(p){

  x <- c()
  for(n in p){
    if (n>=30){
      x <- c(x, "obeso")    
    }else if (n<18.5){
      x <- c(x, "bajo peso")
    }else if (n<30 & n>25){
      x <- c(x, "sobrepeso")
    }else{
      x <- c(x, "normal")
    }
  }
  return(x)

}
```

De cualquier forma, si bien a efectos didácticos esta función es útil, en R, que entiende nativamente de datos vectoriales, existe formas más compactas de resolver esto:

```
condicion = c('bajo peso', 'normal', 'sobrepeso', 'obeso')[findInterval(indice_masa_corporal, c(0, 18.5, 25, 30))]
```

Con `findInterval(indice_masa_corporal, c(0, 18.5, 25, 30))` obtenemos un índice que representa a que intervalo pertenecen los valores de `indice_masa_corporal`, luego simplemente "matcheamos" este índice con la lista ordenada de categorías.